No speedup observed when using openmp in a c++ project
I tried to add parallel execution to my c++ project.
Thus, based on this example I defined my app.cpp as follows:
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>

int sum_serial(int n) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; ++i) {
        sum += i;
    }
    return sum;
}

// Parallel programming function
int sum_parallel(int n) {
    int sum = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+ : sum)
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; ++i) {
        sum += i;
    }
    return sum;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // Beginning of parallel region
#pragma omp parallel
    { printf("Hello World... from thread = %d\n", omp_get_thread_num()); }
    // Set threads number.
#if defined(_OPENMP)
    omp_set_num_threads(2);
#endif

    {
        const int n = 100000000;

        auto start_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        int result_serial = sum_serial(n);

        auto end_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        std::chrono::duration<double> serial_duration = end_time - start_time;

        start_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        int result_parallel = sum_parallel(n);
        end_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::chrono::duration<double> parallel_duration = end_time - start_time;

        std::cout << "Serial result: " << result_serial << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Parallel result: " << result_parallel << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Serial duration: " << serial_duration.count() << " seconds" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Parallel duration: " << parallel_duration.count() << " seconds" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Speedup: " << serial_duration.count() / parallel_duration.count()
                  << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

What surprised me is that there is no speedup, in fact, the parallel execution is quite a lot slower. My output is:
Serial result: 987459712
Parallel result: 987459712
Serial duration: 0.132073 seconds
Parallel duration: 0.645815 seconds
Speedup: 0.204507

Note that my cmake is:
add_executable(wingdesigner app.cpp)
target_compile_features(app PRIVATE cxx_std_17)

add_compile_options(-Wall -O3 -fopenmp)


target_link_libraries(app PUBLIC gomp)

What is wrong?
I must be doing something wrong. I get it that large number of threads can result in barely observable speedup but in this particular case 2 threads compared to 1 should be faster, right?
I assume my compiling is wrong but I can't figure out what the problem would be.

Both versions exhibit Undefined Behaviour. And if it didn't, I'd expect compiler at -O3 to optimise sum_serial to return n*(n+1)/2; and maybe do the the same with sum_parallel if OpenMP doesn't mess it up too much.

sum += i; could be one machine instruction, taking about a nanosecond. Starting new threads takes a lot longer. To "profit", each thread have to do a lot more work to earn back that investment.

check the assembly and compare the two functions

You should not use omp_set_num_threads but the environment variable. The initial parallel section is certainly useless because of that. Runtimes typically re-initialize the parallel section when the number of thread changes (which means re-spawning all the threads).

Threads don't necessarily give a speed gain.   They introduce overhead, and not every type of calculation can be usefully parallelised - doing so| requires discrete subsets of calculations to be sufficiently independent of other subsets that they can be done in parallel (e.g. if one set of calculations computes A and a second set of calculations relies on A having already being computed, then forcing them to be parallelised will invariably take longer than doing them sequentially, due to the additional overhead of threading).

@BoP In fact, I expect compilers to even generate SIMD instructions here on this since auto-vectorization is enabled by default in -O3. On x86-64 machines, SSE2 is used by default by compilers (at least GCC/Clang), so 4 items per instructions and possibly 2 instructions per cycle, that is possibly 8 items/cycles. -mavx2 or even -march=native should help to make it faster on recent CPUs.

high_resolution_clock is not meant to be used for measuring the wall-clock time (not monotonic). Use steady_clock or even better : omp_get_wtime.

@Yksisarvinen Clang can do that but GCC do not yet. This seems to be confirmed by https://godbolt.org/z/KeG1rbKKq . However, Clang seems to fail to use the math trick when OpenMP is used (an inefficient loop is used instead).

I tried your example and noticed that only one thread was used, even with OMP.
As a matter of fact, it seems that your CMake file is wrong (should use target_compile_options instead of add_compile_options). I used the following and observed some speedup:
project (foobar)
add_executable(app app.cpp)
target_compile_features(app PRIVATE cxx_std_17)
target_compile_options (app PUBLIC -Wall -O3 -fopenmp)
target_link_libraries  (app PUBLIC gomp)

I also used the following snippet (using sin) in order to have "more" work to do:
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>
#include <cmath>

auto sum_serial(int n) {
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; ++i) {
        sum += sin(i);
    }
    return sum;
}

// Parallel programming function
auto sum_parallel(int n) {
    double sum = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+ : sum)
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; ++i) {
        sum += sin(i);
    }
    return sum;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // Beginning of parallel region
#pragma omp parallel
    { printf("Hello World... from thread = %d\n", omp_get_thread_num()); }
    // Set threads number.
#if defined(_OPENMP)
    omp_set_num_threads(2);
#endif

    {
        const int n = 100000000;

        auto start_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        auto result_serial = sum_serial(n);

        auto end_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        std::chrono::duration<double> serial_duration = end_time - start_time;

        start_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        auto result_parallel = sum_parallel(n);
        end_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::chrono::duration<double> parallel_duration = end_time - start_time;

        std::cout << "Serial result    : " << result_serial << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Parallel result  : " << result_parallel << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Serial duration  : " << serial_duration.count() << " seconds" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Parallel duration: " << parallel_duration.count() << " seconds" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Speedup          : " << serial_duration.count() / parallel_duration.count() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

I got the following output:
Serial result    : 1.71365
Parallel result  : 1.71365
Serial duration  : 1.08041 seconds
Parallel duration: 0.546919 seconds
Speedup          : 1.97545


The portable way to link OpenMP with CMake is find_package(OpenMP REQUIRED) and then target_link_libraries(app PUBLIC OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX). This selects the compiler-specific OpenMP flag(-qopenmp/-fopenmp/...) and links the appropriate library (which is not always gomp).
